# Accuracy and loss fluctuating in binary classification problem in deep learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

I'm currently working on a classification problem for stroke on UNet. The task is based the size of the lesion area(large - 1, small - 0). Note that the labels is actually produce by me(I will try to improve it) so they are not that accurate. When I trained like 20 epochs, my accuracy waved around 0.5 and loss is around 0.6, which basically says my model makes random choices. So what should I do to make my model learning again?

Here's the Unet I'm using:

```
`import keras_unet
def define_unet(n_filters=neuron,
                    n_layers=4,
                    dropout_rate=0.25):
    model_unet = keras_unet.models.custom_unet(input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3),
                                              activation='relu',
                                              use_batch_norm=True,
                                              upsample_mode='deconv',
                                              dropout=dropout_rate,
                                              dropout_type='spatial',
                                              filters=n_filters,
                                              num_layers=n_layers,
                                              output_activation='linear'
                                              )
    
    GAP = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model_unet.output)        
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid')(GAP)
    model_unet = keras.Model(inputs = model_unet.input, outputs = outputs)
#bce is just the binary crossentropy
    model_unet.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=bce_loss,metrics=['accuracy'])
    model_unet.summary()

    return model_unet`
```

here's the hyperparameters:

```
`learning_rate = 0.0001
epochs = 20
dropout_rate = 0.2
batch_size = 16
kernel_size = 3
neuron = 8
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)`
```

My data set contains 1000 images spilt into 80:20 for training and validation and I'm
using batch_size = 16.
Here's the plot for acc and loss:

[image: acc_plot]
[image: loss_plot]

I've tried to implement a few learning rate and it didn't work:(

Thanks in advance for your help!!!
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use a unet for a classification task?

Answer (score 0):

there are many variances including samples and models to improve the accuracy of binary class-entropy as a single objective. To improves the accuracy first you need to use the correct measurement, the accuracy matric works correctly when you label with 0 to 1 as float since it is binary cross entropy it may reflect minus number result because that is from the square different of the label values.

It is not fluctuating loss and accuracy but you need to use the correct approaches, binary cross-entropy as single is a very fast drive but the return of turn points is deterministic.

Sample: You can apply the mean of all output or simply critical points.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    
    if predictions[0] > 0.51 :
        plt.xlabel(str(list_label_actual[1]) + " score: " + str(predictions[0]))
    else :
        plt.xlabel(str(list_label_actual[0]) + " score: " + str(predictions[0]))
```

Sample: You may try to use vectors to improves of the results.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    # list_label.append([0, 0])
    list_label.append([0.0])
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    # list_label.append([1, 1])
    list_label.append([1.0])

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
log_dir = checkpoint_dir

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 2), dtype=tf.int64)))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.float32)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    # learning_rate=0.001,
    # momentum=0.0,
    # nesterov=False,
    # name='SGD',# )

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    label_smoothing=0.0,
    axis=-1,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='binary_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        # if( logs['loss'] <= 0.2 ):
            # self.model.stop_training = True
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.95 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, validation_data=dataset, batch_size=10, epochs=10000, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_file)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_file[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    
    plt.subplot(5, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_file_actual[i])
    
    if predictions[0] > 0.51 :
        plt.xlabel(str(list_label_actual[1]) + " score: " + str(predictions[0]))
    else :
        plt.xlabel(str(list_label_actual[0]) + " score: " + str(predictions[0]))

plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.5, 1])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

Output results:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piJ2s.png)

Accuracy versus epoaches:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4lSm.png)